# Pure Appengine project is heavily using compute engine API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I discovered that my pure App-Engine project (no Compute Engine Instances at all) is heavily using Google Compute Engine API (26,165 requests) but that is not visible as API use on the dashboard. Additionally, in Quotas I find strange items:

```
Google Compute Engine Networks Global 1 / 15    
Google Compute Engine Firewall rules Global 2 / 200 
Google Compute Engine Routes 2 / 250
```

I could disable the Compute Engine API, but I fear consequences if I don't understand what I am doing here.

Does anyone know further details or experience something similar?

PS: I also noticed that old deployed versions of my appengine-code from 2013 showed up, which I have deleted again.

Comment: Is this a flexible env app? I don't see such info on my standard env (python) app quota page.

Answer (score 0):

My app is a standard env python one.

I do see the quotas you mentioned in the [IAM & Admin Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) page, but with different limits:

```
Google Compute Engine Networks Global 1 / 5    
Google Compute Engine Firewall rules Global 4 / 100 
Google Compute Engine Routes 2 / 200
```

I suspect that these are automatically driven by the standard env GAE infra (as opposed to being configured by the app itself for the flex env). Their visibility might not be intentional, tho.

I do see a few GCE API calls as well (but then my app is not very active) on the [API Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) page:

```
Google Compute Engine API  17
```

I accidentally clicked on this API's `Disable` button and got this warning (potentially hinting at what this API is used for):

> Disable Google Compute Engine API
>
> Code that uses this project's keys, client IDs, or service accounts
>   will not be able to call this API.
>
> Do you want to disable this API: Google Compute Engine API?

By clicking on the actual `Google Compute Engine API` text/link and then to the [Quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/compute_component/quotas) tab I can see:

```
Queries per day     Unlimited   
Queries per 100 seconds     2,000   
Queries per 100 seconds per user    2,000
```

My peak over the last 30 days is 15, so I won't worry about it :)

I do not see any unexpected older app version.